# Solving a complex value coupled ODEs with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, complex

I am a very beginner in Mathematica and I am trying to solve a complex value coupled ODEs with NDSolver. The equations would be like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rKhW.jpg)
[image]

where u refers to u(t) and a refers to a(t), other symbols such as r0, com, delta0 and k are both constants. What's more, a(t) is also a complex value, something like a(t) = exp[i5t].

I tried to write codes shown below to numerically solve and plot u(t). However, the results are not right. The expected results would be something like Fig. 1(d) in the reference paper.

Is there something that I missed or something wrong that I wrote? I would appreciate it if someone could help answer it.

```
r0 = 0.001;
com = 2000;
delta0 = 30;
k = 100;
sol = NDSolve[{a'[t] == -0.5*k*a[t] + 0.5*k - I*(delta0 +u[t])*a[t],                      
    u''[t] == -u[t] - r0*u'[t] + com*a[t]*Conjugate[a[t]],
    a[0] == 1, u[0] == 10, u'[0] == 0},{a, u}, {t, 0, 6000}];
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t]} /. %], {t, 0, 6000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

**Reference**

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rKhW.jpg) Poot M, Fong K Y, Bagheri M, et al. Backaction limits on self-sustained optomechanical oscillations[J]. Physical Review A, 2012, 86(5): 053826.

Comment: @Nasser, Thanks for your suggestions. I have modified my code. I think that the initial conditions need to be tried out. I set a[0] == 1+i in order to imply that a[t] is a complex number. Now I changed a little bit about my code.

Comment: For the plot, you probably want to use a variable in the DE and a complex plotter. For instance: `ReImPlot[Evaluate[{u[t]} /. First[sol]]....`